# why got it this result in array.filter, lambda? javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, lambda, filter

why got it this result in array.filter? why the function return even number? the first element inside function (2%2) equals 0, 0 - 1 = -1 , is a negative number. the negatives numbers should be filtered.

```
var c = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

var b = c.filter(function(a) {

return (a % 2) - 1;

});

//output [2,4,6]
```

i dont understand it, help me pls

other example

```
let c = new Array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80);
var b = c.filter(function(a) {
  return (a % 20) - 10; // but if it is 9, it returns the whole list, it does not filter anything.
});

console.log(b); // [ 20, 40, 60, 80 ]
```

Comment: 0 is a `falsy` value `-1` is not.

Comment: Negative numbers evaluate to true. Open the browsers console and try this: `!!0` and `!!(-1)`

Comment: Just to be clear, `!!` is a double negation, when you use `!` once you 'negate' the variable, changing true to false and false to true. But if you do it 2 times, you get back to the original value. The thing is, if the original value was not a boolean, negating it twice will get you a boolean, because negation accepts many types of arguments, but always returns a boolean.

Comment: [Flasy Values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), @StackSlave could you please share the docs where -1 is considered as falsy value?

Answer (score 1):

`%` is the remainder *(if you divide by the number to the right)* operator. `oddNumber % 2` always produces a remainder `1`. `1 - 1 === 0` and is falsey. `evenNumber % 2` is remainder `0`. `0 - 1 === -1`, which is truthy. Of course, I'm assuming you're using positive numbers, not negative numbers, in your Arrays.

Comment: `oddNumber % 2 always produces a remainder` very true. BUT that remainder will always be `1`. `therefore that remainder - 1` NOPE. `1-1 = 0` which is for sure a falsy value.

Comment: considering `+ve numbers` only. you can explain why I am incorrect `AGAIN`.

Comment: For some reason, I was assuming `-1` was falsey. My bad, I awarded both of your comments on top points.